# Combobox with checklist and having Select all options in Ext Js 4.2

Tags: extjs4.2

I have a requirement to create a combobox with checklist.I am able to do that.
I also want a select all option so that i can select all values which i can not do.Please help me to get this done.

Answer (score 0):

```
    selModel: {
                    selType: 'checkboxmodel',
                    //mode: 'SINGLE',
                    headerWidth: 62,
                    //checkOnly: false,
                    checkOnly: true,//this will check only when you click on checkbox
                    allowDeselect: false,
                    ignoreRightMouseSelection: true,
listeners: {
                    'selectionchange': Ext.bind(function (view, records) {

                    },this)
                }
                },
```

docs:http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.panel.Table-cfg-selModel

when you use this you will get a checkbox in the header we can select and deselect form there